# React not rerendering props when render function is provided

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have issue with understanding why rendering doesn't happen when render function is provided, instead of returning JSX directly.

Here's my example of InputBox component:

```js
export default React => {
  const InputBox = ({ city, setCity, setTime }) => {
    const onInputEnter = createOnInputEnter({ city, setCity, setTime, getCityTime })

    return (
        <div className='InputBox'>
          <input
            defaultValue={city}
            onKeyPress={onInputEnter}
            onFocus={moveFocusAtEnd}
            autoFocus />
        </div>
      )
  }

  return InputBox
}
```

in this case city is rerendered every time I change redux state of city.

```js
export default React => {
  const InputBox = ({ city, setCity, setTime }) => {
    const onInputEnter = createOnInputEnter({ city, setCity, setTime, getCityTime })

    const componentDidMount = async () => {
      const { city: resultCity, time: resultTime } = await getCityTime(city)

      setCity(resultCity)
      setTime(resultTime)
    }

    const render = () => {
      return (
        <div className='InputBox'>
          <input
            defaultValue={city}
            onKeyPress={onInputEnter}
            onFocus={moveFocusAtEnd}
            autoFocus />
        </div>
      )
    }

    return { render, componentDidMount }
  }

  return InputBox
}
```

In this example city is passed only once and not rerendered when redux state changes.

I would like to use latter example, since I use componentDidMount method for initialization.

I am using React and React-Redux in this example.

This is how my InputBox container looks like:

```js
import createInputBox from '../components/InputBox.js'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

...

export default React => {
  const InputBox = createInputBox(React)

  const InputBoxWithReduxStore = connect(
    ({ city }) => ({ city }),
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(InputBox)

  return InputBoxWithReduxStore
}
```

EDIT:

I am including code snippet to show implementation of createOnInputEnter function

```js
function createOnInputEnter ({ city, setCity, setTime, getCityTime }) {
  return async ({ key, target }) => {
    if (key === 'Enter') {
      try {
        const inputCity = target.value

        setTime('...')

        const { city: resultCity, time: resultTime } = await getCityTime(inputCity)

        setCity(resultCity)
        setTime(resultTime)
      } catch (err) {
        const { city: resultCity, time: resultTime } = await getCityTime(city)

        setCity(resultCity)
        setTime(resultTime)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As @zarcode suggested using React.Component, it does not fit my requirements. Since I use Class-less components. More on Mixin part: https://gist.github.com/jquense/47bbd2613e0b03d7e51c

Comment: Please add it in https://codesandbox.io/s/new

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN https://codesandbox.io/s/8kvozyw682

Comment: @PeterParada, where is rendering not happening

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri on catch clause of createOnInputEnter function - city is still the default one, even after you change it in redux state.

Answer (score 1):

componentDidMount will called only once and also works in the bottom-up. 
So for render in every state change you may use componentWillReceieveprops.

Comment: The problem with this solution is I need to access updated props.city from inside createOnInputEnter function, which lies outside componentWillReceiveProps. Maybe I get it wrong, can you show me demonstrative example how this can solve the issue with accessing updated city property inside createOnInputEnter function? I will edit code to show this function implementation.

Comment: Also it's ok that componentDidMount will be called only once, I use it only for initialization and therefore expect to be called only once.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example is a functional component, which you can use if you don't need component lifecycle methods (like componentDidMount).

Your second example is some mixture of the functional component with lifecycle methods, not sure that can work, never tried.
Instead, if you want to use lifecycle methods in your component, I would suggest you use a class component that extends [React.Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html). It should look something like this:

```
...
import {Component} from "react";

export default class InputBox extends Component {
   onInputEnter = () => { 
       const { city, setCity, setTime } = this.props;
       createOnInputEnter({ city, setCity, setTime, getCityTime })
   }

   async componentDidMount() {
     const { city, setCity, setTime } = this.props;
     const { city: resultCity, time: resultTime } = await getCityTime(city)

     setCity(resultCity)
     setTime(resultTime)
   }

   render(){
     return (
       <div className='InputBox'>
         <input
           defaultValue={city}
           onKeyPress={onInputEnter}
           onFocus={moveFocusAtEnd}
           autoFocus />
       </div>
     )
   }
```

}

Comment: Thanks for code example, however I write non-class React. Inspired by: https://github.com/ericelliott/react-pure-component-starter and Mixin recipe from: https://gist.github.com/jquense/47bbd2613e0b03d7e51c.

Answer (score 0):

in first case `const onInputEnter = createOnInputEnter({ city, setCity, setTime, getCityTime })` is inside the render method of the component as it is a functional component.

I am not getting how this concept work but for second example to be same as first one you will need to do something like this:

```
export default React => {
  const InputBox = ({ city, setCity, setTime }) => {

    const componentDidMount = async () => {
      const { city: resultCity, time: resultTime } = await getCityTime(city)

      setCity(resultCity)
      setTime(resultTime)
    }

    const render = () => {
    const { city, setCity, setTime } = this.props;
    const onInputEnter = createOnInputEnter({ city, setCity, setTime, getCityTime })
      return (
        <div className='InputBox'>
          <input
            defaultValue={city}
            onKeyPress={onInputEnter}
            onFocus={moveFocusAtEnd}
            autoFocus />
        </div>
      )
    }

    return { render, componentDidMount }
  }

  return InputBox
}
```

Although I am not sure if this is the way to access the props inside render here.